# Should Project References be avoided between C++ projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, project-reference

Our large C++ solution has a lot of project references between different projects and it seems to cause problems, most commonly it will try to link the wrong version of the dependency e.g. You'll build `Project` in release and get an error about missing library `dependency_d.lib`. Especially if you are using multiple build configurations.

Are project references considered bad practice working in C++ and developers should stick with the old way (#include directories and libraries listed in project settings)? Or does this simply suggest they've been set up wrong in our solution?

Answer (score 0):

In our team we use #include despite of using vcpkg for the most libraries.

But you can set up different dependencies for each build configuration (Debug, Release etc.): just select desired Configuration at the top if the Project properties window. Your dependency **_d** .lib seems to be a Debug library.

I think there are some problems in your config. Also I haven't heard anything about project references are bad practice.

Comment: that's the point, if you set a project reference how does it know which build configuration to depend on?

Comment: @Mr.Boy, did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694415/c-sharp-vs2008-add-separate-debug-release-references-to-a-project)?